# Download bar not working properly, Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, download

So I made an application in Python to download a file from the internet by clicking a button on the interface. The user also has to name the file before downloading. The file being downloaded is the Microsoft virus definitions (since it's a large file). I have a progress bar to show the progress of the download but I have run into one of two problems:

This is one method I tried, and when I click the button, the file downloads, but the progress bar immediately shows it's completed. Here is the code:

```
def download():
    link = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87341"
    filename = "C:/My Python Apps/" + txtName.get() +".exe"

    r = requests.get(link, stream=True)
    f = open(filename, "wb")
    fileSize = int(r.headers["Content-Length"])
    chunk = 1
    chunkSize = 1024
    bars = int(fileSize/chunkSize)
    print(dict(num_bars=bars))
    with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunkSize), total=bars, unit="KB",
                          desc=filename, leave=True):
            fp.write(chunk)
            progress["value"] = fileSize
    return
```

The other method I tried works a little better, in the sense that when the download begins, it doesn't shoot to the end of the bar immediately. But the problem is before the download has even reached 1%, the bar has already progressed to completed even though the file is still downloading. Here is the code for this function:

```
    link = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87341"
    filename = "C:/My Python Apps/" + txtName.get() +".exe"

    r = requests.get(link, stream=True)

    totalSize = int(r.headers.get("content-length", 0))

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        i = 0
        for data in tqdm(r.iter_content(32*1024), total=totalSize, unit="B", unit_scale=True):
            f.write(data)
            progress["value"] = i
            i += 1
        return
```

How can I get the progress bar to indicate the progress of the download accurately and properly?

Here is the full code of my application if it helps:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, ttk


def downloadThread():
    Thread(target=download).start()

def download():

    # Place either of the functions in the question here...


root = Tk()

w = 400
h = 135
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
wh = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (wh / 2) - (h / 2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
root.title("MyApp beta")

lblName = Label(root, text="File name: ")
lblName.place(x=5, y=5)
txtName = Entry(root, width=25)
txtName.place(x=5, y=25)
value = IntVar()
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=155)
progress.place(x=5, y=50)
btnDownload = Button(root, text="Download Definition", width=21,
                     command=lambda: downloadThread())
btnDownload.place(x=5, y=100)
lblLoad = Label(root, text="Downloading, please wait...")
lblLoad.place_forget()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first implementation, you set the value of the progress bar to the full file size straight away. What you want is to make it a fraction of the file size (the one downloaded already).

This works:

```
def download():
    link = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87341"
    filename = "C:/My Python Apps/" + txtName.get() +".exe"

    r = requests.get(link, stream=True)
    f = open(filename, "wb")
    fileSize = int(r.headers["Content-Length"])
    chunk = 1
    downloaded = 0 # keep track of size downloaded so far
    chunkSize = 1024
    bars = int(fileSize/chunkSize)
    print(dict(num_bars=bars))
    with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunkSize), total=bars, unit="KB",
                          desc=filename, leave=True):
            fp.write(chunk)
            downloaded += chunkSize # increment the downloaded
            progress["value"] = (downloaded*100/fileSize)#*100 #Default max value of tkinter progress is 100
    return
```

*By the way, you did not import `tqdm`: it took lots of time to figure out what that was.*

Comment: You legend it works! :D. Apologies for the tqdm import missing, I accidently didn't highlight it when copying my code. But thanks so much.